# how to implement the filter effect algorithm(such as DUOTONE and COLOR WATCH) in iOS 16 wallpaper Settings?

Tags: filter, opengl-es, glsl

After i update my iphone version to 16, i find a new feature in Setting/Wallpaper/Customize/Photo which can set different image filter to show different effects.

I would like to know how these filter algorithms(DUOTONE and COLOR WASH filter) are implemented, such as if using GLSL, how should i write the shading language, or if using LUT, how should i generate the LUT files.

As an example, if I wanted to implement a black and white filter, I would write the following shading language:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uTextureUnit;

//float[] filterValue = new float[]{0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f};
in vec3 vFilter;
in vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec4 vFragColor;
void main() {
     vec4 vTextureColor = texture(uTextureUnit,vTexCoord);
     float vFilterColor = (vFilter.x * vTextureColor.r + vFilter.y * vTextureColor.g + vFilter.z * vTextureColor.b);
     vFragColor = vec4(vFilterColor, vFilterColor, vFilterColor, 1.0);
}
```